# Creating a Windows Task that runs when enabled and periodically thereafter until disabled

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I'm a bit confused about triggering in windows task scheduler.

I want to create a task that runs upon being enabled by the user, and as long as it stays enabled I want it to also run periodically (say for example hourly, whether logged on or off), and also at system startup as well, until the user manually disables the task. Is that set by using one trigger, or two, and what settings should be used for the triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is that set by using one trigger, or two, and what settings should be used for the triggers?

I think you will need 2 triggers for this.

> I want to create a task that runs upon being enabled by the user, and as long as it stays enabled I want it to also run periodically (say for example hourly, whether logged on or off), and also at system startup as well, until the user manually disables the task.

Try the following:

1. Start > Run > Task Scheduler
2. Click "Create Task"

   [image]
3. Click "General" tab

   - Enable "Run whether user is logged on or not" then click "OK"

   [image]
4. Click "Triggers" then click "New"

   - Select "At Startup" then click "OK"

   [image]
5. Click "Triggers" then click "New"

   - Select "On a schedule"
   - Set "Start" date and time as appropriate
   - Enable "Daily"
   - "Recur every" to 1 "days"
   - Set Repeat task every" to 1 hour
   - Set "for a duration of" to Indefinitely
   - Click "OK"

   [image]

   [image]
6. Select the "Actions" tab and click "New"

   - Complete as appropriate and click OK.

   [image]
7. Click "OK" a final time to finish creating the task.
8. Test it all works as expected.